# Expressing lp distances by polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, optimization

For a point $\mathbf{a}\in \mathbb R^d$ and a $r$-dimensional space represented by $\mathbf{U}\subset \mathbb R^{d\times r}$(orthonormal basis), the $l_p$ distance of $\mathbf{a}$ from $\mathbf{U}$ is defined as $$d^p(\mathbf{a,U})=\min_{x\in \mathbb R^r}\|\mathbf{Ux-a}\|_p^p$$

For a given $p$, I am looking for a polynomial, $P(\mathbf{U})$, on $r\times d$ variables where variables stands for entries of $\mathbf{U}$ such that $P(\mathbf{U})=d^p(\mathbf{a,U})$.
For example for $p=2$, we have $P(\mathbf{U})=\|\mathbf{U}^Ta\|^2$.
Can we do the same for other values of $p\in[1,\infty)$? If not exact does there exist polynomials which provide a good approximation to $d^p(\mathbf{a,U})$?

Also is there a closed form expression for calculating $d^p(\mathbf{a,U})$.
Any help, comments, references are greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: The $l_p$ distance to power $p$ even between points is only a polynomial in coordinates when $p$ is an even integer, otherwise, it is not even analytic. And what is "orthonormal basis" in $l_p$?